# PowerShell unordered HTML list

Tags: html, powershell

I'm trying to create a function to generate an unordered HTML list. This works fine when I use it like `ConvertTo-HTMLlist $MyArray`, but not when I pipe information to it like `$MyArray | ConvertTo-HTMLlist`.

**My function:**

```
Function ConvertTo-HTMLlist {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$True)]
    Param (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        $Array
    )
    Process {
        $Array = @(foreach ($_ in $Array) {"<li>" + $_ + "<br><br></li>"}) # Add extra space
        $Array = ,"<ul>$($Array | Sort-Object)</ul>"
        $Array = $Array.Replace("<br><br></li></ul>", "</li></ul>") # Remove last double breaks
        $Array += "<p><i><font size=`"2`">* Native PowerShell errors are displayed in <font color=`"red`">red</font>.</font></i></p>"
        Write-Output $Array
    }
}
```

**Results:**

```
$MyArray = 'Apples', 'Peers', 'Bananas'

ConvertTo-HTMLlist $MyArray

# Correct result:
<ul><li>Apples<br><br></li> <li>Bananas<br><br></li> <li>Peers</li></ul><p><i><font size="2">* Native PowerShell errors are displayed in <font color="red">red</font>.</f
ont></i></p>

$MyArray | ConvertTo-HTMLlist

# Incorrect result:    
<ul><li>Apples</li></ul><p><i><font size="2">* Native PowerShell errors are displayed in <font color="red">red</font>.</font></i></p>
<ul><li>Peers</li></ul><p><i><font size="2">* Native PowerShell errors are displayed in <font color="red">red</font>.</font></i></p>
<ul><li>Bananas</li></ul><p><i><font size="2">* Native PowerShell errors are displayed in <font color="red">red</font>.</font></i></p>
```

There should be a way to collect everything from the pipeline first, and then start handling it.

Comment: IMHO there's no way to do this, just because pipeline is intended to process one element at a time. Here you process all elements (the entire array) in one shot. In a same way as @mjolinor told you,  you can use: `,$myarray | ConvertTo-HTMLlist` as a workaround.

Comment: Thanks CB for the feedback. In the meantime I've found a solution, check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because everything is possible in PowerShell, I've played a bit more with the `Begin`, `Process` and `End` clauses in a function. And I think I've got it working as desired:

```
$MyArray = 'Apples', 'Peers', 'Bananas'

Function ConvertTo-HTMLlist {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$True)]
    Param (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        $Array
    )
    Begin {
        $tmpArray = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    }
    Process {
        $Array | ForEach-Object {
            $tmpArray.Add("<li>" + $_ + "<br><br></li>") | Out-Null
        }
    }
    End {
        $tmpArray = ,"<ul>$($tmpArray | Sort-Object)</ul>"
        $tmpArray = $tmpArray.Replace("<br><br></li></ul>", "</li></ul>") # Remove last double breaks
        $tmpArray += "<p><i><font size=`"2`">* Native PowerShell errors are displayed in <font color=`"red`">red</font>.</font></i></p>"
        Write-Output $tmpArray
    }
}

Write-Host "Piped result:" -ForegroundColor Yellow
$MyArray | ConvertTo-HTMLlist

Write-Host "Non piped result:" -ForegroundColor Yellow
ConvertTo-HTMLlist $MyArray
```

Let me know what you think.